# Git issue after reset

Tags: php, git

I have had a problem the last day. I read up on the best way to handle it and went through a git reset and it worked fine.

I had to do it again and after that I have had an issue. When I go to run drush fl I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class backup_migrate_destination_db in /Library/WebServer/Documents/con_Ecgcme/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/backup_migrate/includes/destinations.db.inc on line 311
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                          [error]
Error: Cannot redeclare class backup_migrate_destination_db in
/Library/WebServer/Documents/con_Ecgcme/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/backup_migrate/includes/destinations.db.inc, line
311
```

I have no idea what to do. Can anyone share some thoughts?
thanks!

Comment: That appears to be a PHP error message, not a `git` one. Consider retagging so folks more familiar with PHP might help out. Looks like you've got more than one declaration of the mentioned class in different places, though...

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, this was a typo I figured out. The issue was the typo being read and causing the issue. I was trying to solve a git issue when this popped up, hence the tag for git.